# Is there a framework for distributed job/workers in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, akka, distributed-computing, distributed-system, akka.net

I'm working on project that require distributing worker services framework in .net core

description example:

I have a `.netcore` prime server `web app mvc` that has a millions of work item to done `for example 1 million of urls should be crawlered`

also I have 10 `web apis` with the same logic to crawl received urls. each api deployed on it's own server

what I'm looking for?

I'm looking for frameworks or tool help me the following

- prime server `web app mvc`

  1- has a queue of work items

  2- Load Balancing to forward items to `worker service`

  3- health check of all `worker services` real time reporting

  4- real time communication of all **Nodes** `worker service` of current processing items

  5- plus handling errors `(connectivity, outage)`

[image: distributed worker]

> so I have notice [akka.net](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net) but didn't get in depth of it yet

Is there any framework/tool help me do this ?

Comment: Did you look into NServiceBus? https://particular.net

Comment: @SeanFarmar Not yet, do have any idea is ```NServiceBus``` fit to my case , showing example ?

Comment: sorry, I dropped the ball on this. Still interested?

Comment: @Sean I've started implementation, but your inputs is most welcome